# Blank space Issue while navigating betwen the charts in one report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In ssrs, I have a report which has four charts in it.
The four charts has the same design.
when i preview it,the first chart is set to shown by default and
we have a link on first chart that should redirect to the third chart.

when we preview it, the position of the first chart is displayed correctly just below the header of the report and when we click the link which should navigate to the third chart, we are getting the third chart but the position of the chart is changing.

It is occupying more blank space between the header and the chart so that we are not able to view the chart at one time.

How can we remove the space between the header and the chart so that the position of the third chart should be same as the position of the first chart.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please add the screen shot with the Blank space.

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot would help here.

A common issue is overlapping controls that, when rendered, shift one another around in sometimes unexpected ways.  Double check to make sure that the chart control isn't sitting directly atop anything else in your RDL.